# Initialization list to constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initialization-list

I'm working on an assignment in school where we are supposed to make a constructor to our own List-class that takes an initialization list as an argument.

This is what I want to be able to do:

```
List ourList {1, 2, 3};
```

This is what I have so far:

```
List::List(std::initializer_list<int> il)
{
  head_ = copy(il.begin(), il.end());
}

List_Node* List::copy(std::initializer_list<int>::iterator begin,
                      std::initializer_list<int>::iterator end)
{
  if(begin == end)
    return nullptr;

  List_Node* new_list = new List_Node(*begin);

  List_Node* node = copy(begin++, end);
  new_list->next_ = node;
  return new_list;
}
```

In my humble opinion, this should work great. However, when I try my initialization (`List list {1,2,3};`) I get a seg-fault. Could someone please explain what it is I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You keep copying the same element over and over, you want `++begin` not `begin++`

Comment: Why use recurrence for a sequential task? It only makes the bug harder to spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List_Node* node = copy(begin++, end);
```

This will call `copy` again with the same arguments, recursing forever and never completing.

You should have been able to tell this by using a debugger to see where it crashed, and you would have seen that there were hundreds of calls to `List::copy`, not the three calls you expected.

You want `++begin` not `begin++`

Comment: I think you could explain the difference between `op++` and `++op` so the OP gets a lil' bit smarter. That would be nice IMO.

Comment: @luk32 Thanks, but I know how op++ and ++op works. Just a brainfart from me this time =/